# Get value Input Hidden inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of hidden input, (.red is a div child of Div_Gral)
Here is what I did:

```
$('#div_Gral').each(function () {

  var tiem = "";
  tiem = $(this).find(".red > hidden").val();

  if (tiem = "") {

  } else { 
    alert(tiem); 
  }

});
```

Comment: `hidden` isn't a valid css selector.  `.red > hidden` says find a child <hidden> tag inside elements with a class of 'red'

Comment: Try this: `$("#div_Gral .red input[type=hidden]").val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.each` on your div, since it only iterates through a list, which your div isn't. You first need to get all the elements with the `red` class and then iterate through them. Also, in order to know if something is hidden, you could use `.is(":hidden")`, which will return either true or false. The following code should give you an idea.

```js
// Fetch all inputs that have the clas "red"
var inputs = $('#div_Gral').find('.red');

// Now iterate through them and check if they are hidden.
$(inputs).each(function() {

  // If so, show an alert with it's value.
  if($(this).is(":hidden")) {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_Gral">
  <input class="red" value="I am not hidden.">
  <input class="red" hidden="hidden" value="I am hidden.">
</div>
```